# AWS using API Gateway and Cloud Front in the same domain with different path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using the API Gateway v2 and Cloud Front on my system, and serverless framework (with compose) to manage everything.

How to expose both services in the same domain (to avoid preflight requests and a few other internal requirements) where each is accessible with a custom path?

Example:

- https://foo.bar/app -> points to the Cloud Front application
- https://foo.bar/api -> points to the API Gateway
- https://foo.bar -> redirects to the Cloud Front in /app initially but later it will have its own SPA landing page.

Anything I can do? The only way we were able to configure this was by creating an edge lambda to handle requests and decide whether the CF or the API would be used but this solution seems to waste resources unnecessarily...

Thanks.

Comment: Lambda@Edge seems like a good solution. No other way to do it that I can think of. Maybe you could use app.foo.bar and api.foo.bar instead?

Comment: @BenWhaley yes, exactly our thoughts but then we will have preflight requests...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the behavior and origin feature of cloudfront.

Have multiple origins for example S3 bucket and another api gateway.

Then based on behavior you can route to specific origin.

Like `Default(*)` behavior will point to `S3`.

`/api/*` behavior will point to api gateway.

https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/add-cloudfront-behavior-and-origin.html code.

Much detail explanation
https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/api-gateway-and-cloud-front-in-same.html